# How to execute a batch of Selenium tests in parallel on a Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I have a Selenium Grid host on **machine H** and I have two grid nodes: **machine N1** and **machine N2**. Both nodes have the same capabilities.

I have four tests: **test1** => **test4.** I launch the tests on the host machine using **nunit** console: `nunit3-console Test.dll --where="method =~ Test"`.

All tests are executed on **machine N1**. When I launch them again, all tests are executed on **machine N2**. Next time on **machine N1** and so on.

I expected to have **test1** executed on **N1**, **test2** on **N2**, **test3** on **N1** and **test4** on **N2**.

I tried to put "[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]" in AssemblyInfo.cs but that didn't help. The tests are still all executed on the same node.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Grid in C# Parallel execution with Nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993258/selenium-grid-in-c-sharp-parallel-execution-with-nunit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the NUnit3 [Parallelizable](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) attribute. If you put the `[Parallelizable]` annotation above each test fixture (class), then each class's tests will run as a group on a separate browser/tab. To get a Test to run on a specific node, you'll need to define a [desiredCapability](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities). I use the undocumented applicationName capability to do so.